# Bluetooth connect works on some devices

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have developed an app that connects to a bluetooth device, it scans for devices and automatically connects when the right one is found.

The app works on on Lenovo A1010 (API 22) and Huawei P10 (API 24), but not on Huawei P8 (API 23).

The P8 seems to be unable to connect. Nothing really happens after `BluetoothDevice#connectGatt (Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback)` is called. When the device is turned off `onConnectionStateChange(...)` is called with `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED`.

autoConnect is set to false. The behaviour is the same when connecting and when trying to reconnect.

I have successfully used other bluetooth apps on the P8 to make sure that there is nothing wrong with the device. I have been unsuccessful in trying to activate the BtSnoop log on the P8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It scanned for other devices continuously without a pause when connecting. The P8 is unable to connect while scanning.